# dot product identity

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

$$a \cdot (a \cdot b)=(a \cdot a)(a \cdot b)$$

Is this identity true when $a$ and $b$ are vectors, and when $\cdot$ is the dot product operator?  And assuming that $()()$ means multiplying the contents of the parentheses.

Can anyone please post explanation and links of this identity?  I saw it used somewhere, but I cannot seem to find documentation of it in textbooks or in search engine research using the key words I could think of.

Thank you.

---

It is used in a suggested solution for the following problem:

"Show that the vector orth_a b = b - proj_a b is orthogonal to a.  (It is called an orthogonal projection of b.)"

Where a and b are vectors, and proj_a b is the vector projection of b onto a.

Really what I need is to learn to answer this problem, and the part of the suggested proof I don't understand is given in my initial post above.  If you have a better answer to this problem, I would love to learn how your approach works.

Comment: Note that $a$ is a vector and $a\cdot b$ is a scalar, so $a\cdot (a\cdot b)$ is not defined. Perhaps you mean something else?

Comment: @AlexBecker, Thank you.  Please see my edit of my original post above.  It is placed under the dividing line under thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have two vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ you can take their dot product: $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}$. This dot product is a scalar (number). It is indeed sometimes called the scalar product.

It does not make sense to take a dot product of a vector with a scalar, so what you have written on the left hand side is not well defined (since here you have the dot-product of a vector $\vec{a}$ and a scalar $(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b})$.

If you want, you can take a look at the [Wikipedia article on the dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Properties). Under properties, you can find a few formulas. Try to go through them and convince yourself that they are well defined (i.e. that you only have dot products between vectors - noting of course that one can multiply a vector by a scalar)

Edit: Just to add a bit more about your original problem. You have that 
$$
proj_\vec{a}(\vec{b}) = \frac{\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b}}{\lvert \vec{a} \lvert^2}\vec{a}
$$
and
$$
orth_\vec{a}(\vec{b}) = \vec{b} - proj_\vec{a}(\vec{b}).
$$
So show that $\vec{a}$ and $orth_\vec{a}(\vec{b})$ are orthogonal you conpute their dot product:
$$
\begin{align}
\vec{a}\cdot (\vec{b} - proj_\vec{a}(\vec{b})) &= \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} - \vec{a}\cdot proj_\vec{a}(\vec{b}) \\
&= \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} - \vec{a}\cdot \frac{\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b}}{\lvert \vec{a} \lvert^2}\vec{a} \\
&= \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} - \frac{\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b}}{\lvert \vec{a} \lvert^2}\vec{a}\cdot \vec{a} \\
&= \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} - \frac{\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b}}{\lvert \vec{a} \lvert^2}\lvert \vec{a}\vert^2 \\
&= \dots
\end{align}
$$

You can probably finish it from here.

Comment: Thank you.  Please see my edit to my original post above.  I did look at the wikipedia posting.  This is really an attempt to answer the broader problem that I added in my edit above.  I think that the suggested proof I was given might not be right.  I would love to hear your suggestions as to how to better show the result requested in my edit to my original posting above.  Thank you.

Comment: @CodeMed: did my edit help?

Comment: Thank you.  Actually, the very next step at the end of your edit is the part about which I posted my initial question above: a.a.b=?  Can you elaborate the next couple steps?

Comment: @CodeMed: sure, I will edit

Comment: @CodeMed: Did that help?

Comment: Perfect.  That is the answer.  Now I understand the thing that sparked this posting. +1